# Using file system in Qt C++

Tags: c++, sql, qt, file, system

I have created a basic UI in Qt with lots of text fields, now i want to use the text or number that the user enters and store it in a file ( preferably a SQL db file, but a text file will do just fine).

after saving the file I should be able to access that info again such that it lays out everything in a tabular format.

Comment: Can you post some code on what have you tried till now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See QTextStream class:

```
 QFile data("output.txt");
 if (data.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate)) {
     QTextStream out(&data);
     out << yourLabel->text();
 }
```

You can read your data in similar way.

Comment: I'd suggest using `QSaveFile` in Qt 5.1 & up - it won't cause loss of data should the writing fail. I also suggest not using anything below Qt 5.1 for that very reason. Destroying your user's data is not cool. If you need to safely store settings in Qt 4, use `QSettings`, not `QFile`.